# List manipulation with Python

Tags: python, json, list, if-statement

I have a huge JSON file containing article's titles and main body as it can be seen below.

```
{
    "paragraphs": [
        "Ismael Omar Guelleh, known in Djibouti by his initials, IOG, won a second term in a one-man presidential race in 2005 and a third term in April 2011.", 
        "Parliament - which does not include any representatives of the opposition - approved an amendment to the constitution in 2010 allowing the president to run for a third term.", 
        "The constitutional reforms also cut the presidential mandate to five years from six, and created a senate.", 
        "Mr Guelleh succeeded his uncle and Djibouti's first president, Hassan Gouled Aptidon, in April 1999 at the age of 52. He was elected in a multi-party ballot.", 
        "Mr Guelleh supports Djibouti's traditionally strong ties with France and has tried to reconcile the different factions in neighbouring Somalia."
    ], 
    "description": "A profile of Djibouti's political leader, President Guelleh", 
    "title": "Djibouti profile"
},
```

What I want to do is every time I append a title and its corresponding paragraphs to a list, I want to include titles who have four or more paragraphs (i.e. the example I posted above has 5 so I want it included). I tried to print paragraphs length with :

```
print len(y['paragraphs']
```

and it works but I cannot use it in order to control what will be appended.

I am using this code in Python:

```
titles = []
vocabulary = []
paragraphs = []

with open("/Users/.../file.json") as j:
data = json.load(j)


for x in range(0,len(data)):
    titles.append(data[x]['title'])
    paragraphs.append(data[x]['paragraphs'])

for y in range(3000, 3500):
   # here I believe there must be an if statement
    vocabulary.append(titles[y])
    vocabulary.append(paragraphs[y][0])
    vocabulary.append(paragraphs[y+1][0])
```

I tried adding an if statement after the second for like:

```
if len(y['paragraphs']) > 4:
```

And I got this error:
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I know the solution is a simple one line of code but I am stuck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the `range(3000, 3500)` doing?

Comment: I use it to get titles and paragraphs between entry 3000 and 3500 (it will go up to 3499). If you see on the upper for I have first appended all the data I need from the JSON to lists titles and paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You define `y` in the `for` loop

```
for y in range(3000, 3500):
```

This means `y` will take on values of `3000`, `3001`, ... `3499`. These are all values of `int`. Therefore the line below is trying to use a `dict` lookup (`.getitem`) on an `int` which does not exist obviously.

```
if len(y['paragraphs']) > 4:
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what was needed was:

```
for y in range(3000, 3500):
    length = len(paragraphs[y])
    if length > 4:
    ...
```